# How to call a different activity depending on the selected list item?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have a listview with 3 sections. I want that an item of each section go to a different activity. But is not that easy because the list can change dynamically. I mean, I can add or remove items.

Comment: If you set an onItemClickListener it can return a position that is clicked. If you simply get the right item out of the collection and navigate to the corresponding activity after that it would work.

Answer (score 0):

From the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) the method, `public abstract boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event)` ,

> Called when a touch event is dispatched to a view. This allows
>   listeners to get a chance to respond before the target view.

```
    public class Newuser extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{


        ListView displaylist;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.SampleClass);

            displaylist  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            String[] listofitems = {"A","B","C","W"};

            ArrayAdapter<String> lists = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SampleClass.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listofitems);

            displaylist.setAdapter(lists);

            displaylist.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }


    // Here is the code for List view on touch

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

// You can call your activity here.
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(SampleClass.this,AnotherClass.class);

            startActivity(intent1);


            return true;
        }


    }
```